# Unable to install silverlight in Ubuntu 16.04 after using tutorial from multiple sites

Tags: 16.04, wine, libraries, pipelight, moonlight

I have followed these procedures:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
sudo update
sudo apt install wine-staging
sudo apt install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipeline-plugin --update
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable flash
pipelight-plugin --system-check
```

Here I am getting the following error:

```
>> 32 bit <<

Checking Wine version ...
Version: wine-1.9.7 (Staging)
Patched Wine version: PASSED
(Run '/usr/share/pipelight/wine --patches' for more details.)

wine: DLL not found.
Checking OpenGL ...
OpenGL Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL Direct Rendering: True
OpenGL: PASSED

Checking fonts ...
Found Arial in Z:\usr\share\fonts\truetype\msttcorefonts\Arial.ttf
Found Arial in Z:\usr\share\fonts\truetype\msttcorefonts\Arial_Bold.ttf
Found Arial in Z:\usr\share\fonts\truetype\msttcorefonts\arialbi.ttf
Found Arial in Z:\usr\share\fonts\truetype\msttcorefonts\ariali.ttf
Found Verdana in Z:\usr\share\fonts\truetype\msttcorefonts\Verdana.ttf
Found Verdana in Z:\usr\share\fonts\truetype\msttcorefonts\verdanab.ttf
Found Verdana in Z:\usr\share\fonts\truetype\msttcorefonts\Verdana_Bold_Italic.ttf
Found Verdana in Z:\usr\share\fonts\truetype\msttcorefonts\Verdana_Italic.ttf
Fonts: PASSED

Checking ACLs / XATTR ...
ACLs: PASSED

Checking libraries...
libcairo.so.2: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2
libcapi20.so.3: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcapi20.so.3
libcups.so.2: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcups.so.2
libdbus-1.so.3: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3
libfontconfig.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1
libfreetype.so.6: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
libGL.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
libgnutls.so.30: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30
libgobject-2.0.so.0: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
libgsm.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgsm.so.1
libgtk-3.so.0: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
libjpeg.so.8: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
libncurses.so.5: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5
libnetapi.so: missing
libodbc.so.2: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2
libOSMesa.so.8: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libOSMesa.so.8
libpcap.so.0.8: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcap.so.0.8
libpng12.so.0: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
libsane.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsane.so.1
libtiff.so.5: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5
libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0
libv4l1.so.0: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l1.so.0
libva.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libva.so.1
libva-drm.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libva-drm.so.1
libva-x11.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libva-x11.so.1
libX11.so.6: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
libX11-xcb.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1
libXcomposite.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1
libXcursor.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1
libXext.so.6: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6
libXi.so.6: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6
libXinerama.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1
libXrandr.so.2: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2
libXrender.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1
libxslt.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1
libXxf86vm.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1
Libraries: FAILURE

>> 64 bit <<

Checking Wine version ...
Version: wine-1.9.7 (Staging)
Patched Wine version: PASSED
(Run '/usr/share/pipelight/wine64 --patches' for more details.)

wine: DLL not found.
Checking OpenGL ...
OpenGL Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL Direct Rendering: True
OpenGL: PASSED

Checking fonts ...
Found Arial in Z:\usr\share\fonts\truetype\msttcorefonts\Arial.ttf
Found Arial in Z:\usr\share\fonts\truetype\msttcorefonts\Arial_Bold.ttf
Found Arial in Z:\usr\share\fonts\truetype\msttcorefonts\arialbi.ttf
Found Arial in Z:\usr\share\fonts\truetype\msttcorefonts\ariali.ttf
Found Verdana in Z:\usr\share\fonts\truetype\msttcorefonts\Verdana.ttf
Found Verdana in Z:\usr\share\fonts\truetype\msttcorefonts\verdanab.ttf
Found Verdana in Z:\usr\share\fonts\truetype\msttcorefonts\Verdana_Bold_Italic.ttf
Found Verdana in Z:\usr\share\fonts\truetype\msttcorefonts\Verdana_Italic.ttf
Fonts: PASSED

Checking ACLs / XATTR ...
ACLs: PASSED

Checking libraries...
libcairo.so.2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code./usr/bin/pipelight-plugin: line 420: 10315 Aborted                 (core dumped) "$PIPELIGHT_SHARE_PATH/wine64" --check-libs
Libraries: FAILURE
```

What to do now?

Comment: What indeed. I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: From now [read this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896588/silverlight-not-working-in-firefox) about Silverlight in FF

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've managed to solve this problem. The key was the following command:

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins
```

Then restart Firefox/ Chrome and voila - Silverlight works smoothly.

If you still have some problems, please make sure that `--list-enabled`, launched without `sudo`, returns desired plugins, for example:

```
$ pipelight-plugin --list-enabled
silverlight5.1
```

Hope it will help anybody!

---

BTW: interesting thing though is that:

```
pipelight-plugin --system-check
```

still fails with the same error :-) but it seems to be irrelevant.