# Silverlight not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I have followed the instructions for installation of Pipelight here, but to no avail:

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/enabling-silverlight-in-firefox/6908

It may be worth noting that the file `pluginreg.dat` contains the following after all is said and done:

```
Generated File. Do not edit.

[HEADER]
Version:0.18t:$
Arch:x86-gcc3:$

[PLUGINS]
libfreshwrapper-flashplayer.so:$
/usr/lib/browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash/libfreshwrapper-flashplayer.so:$
13.1.2.3:$
1477307377000:0:0:0:$
Shockwave Flash 13.1 r2:$
Shockwave Flash:$
2
0:application/x-shockwave-flash:Shockwave Flash:swf:$
1:application/futuresplash:FutureSplash Player:spl:$

[INVALID]
/usr/lib/pipelight/libpipelight-silverlight5.1.so:$
1490396453000:$
```

Any ideas? Here are the contents of `/etc/lsb-release` if it helps:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox 52 ended support for NPAPI plugins other than Flash.

For more information see [Firefox 52 Release Notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/52.0/releasenotes/) and the [accompanying blog post](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/).

Comment: Well. So much for that.

Answer (score 1):

Pipelight support has ended since [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/) and silverlight works with Firefox for windoze.